# Unix Scipt Shell: alert on change of specific files

Tags: unix, shell-script, monitoring

Could any one Help me with the script

Im trying to make a script shell that will alerts/email the root if any of those files has been modified and the script has to auto routine , so the script have to be running at all time

I'm tried doing something to start with but i need some one to correct me or give me ideas

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
if [`find . -mtime -0` -eq date];then
    mail -s "modified files" root

    find  /etc/passwd /etc/shadow /etc/group /etc/gshadow /etc/sudoers /etc/hosts /etc/sysconfig/network /etc/resolv.conf /etc/bashrc /etc/fstab -type f -mtime -50

else
    mail -s "nothing" root
fi
```

Comment: Is this for security? Just I could edit the file without changing the timestamp. hashing would be better and you would also need to make sure that no one could tamper with what you think the hashes are, Tripwire has all that built in.

Comment: i just want to be make a shell script that will email the root if any of the files listed above have been modified

Comment: I'm doing this for a school assignment and I'm not allowed to install any programs, it has to be build in and used only terminal with a file name extension ./File.Sh

Answer (score 0):

I would be strongly tempted to install [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) and use the timestamp checking.  Your config to check a file would be as simple as this.  Though this only watches time timestamp.

```
check file passwd with path /etc/passwd
  if changed timestamp then alert
  if changed checksum then alert
```

Another thing you might want to do is to install [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/), which puts your /etc into git or your prefered vcs.  Setup daily commits for to flush any changes.  With /etc under in a VCS you can see what was changed when.

If you use etckeeper and git as your vcs, you could also setup a post-commit hook that sends an email when the files you are interested in are modified, this could even include a diff of exactly what change was made.

Comment: I'm doing this for a school assignment and I'm not allowed to install any programs, it has to be build in and used only terminal with a file name extension ./File.Sh